# jQuery Positioning Requires <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can open a dialog like this in jQuery:

```
position: {
    of: $( "#Parent" ), 
    my: "left top", 
    at: "left top"
}
```

This works fine in FF, but in IE9 it works only when the doctype is set to `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` and not another like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

It seems that all other doctypes put IE in quirks mode.

The problem is that using `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` messes up ActiveWidgets; the grid won't show in any browser.

Can I have jQuery positioning working without `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` in IE? Or can I make ActiveWidgets work with this recommended DOCTYPE?

---

Thanks for the answers

After spending one day to replace activeWidgets grid by jqwidgets, I finally didn't like the result. I use PHP templates to generate dynamic grids from ini text files.

I ended up dividing my document into 2 iframes. One with dialogs and other with grid

such way i cannot move dialogs outside the frame but it works

this is great community that helped me a lot designing great Intranet site 
thanks

Comment: have you run page through w3c validator to be sure you don't have broken tags somewhere? WHat are `ActiveWidgets` ?

Comment: It sounds like you have some code which depends on Standards mode, and ActiveWidgets as a third party library which depends on Quirks mode. You can't have both modes active in the same document, so the appropriate action is to replace ActiveWidgets with something that is reasonable designed instead of being an unprofessional mess. (Based on the description of ActiveWidgets - replace it with YUI, jQuery UI, or Dojo)

Answer (score 2):

**tldr; use a *valid/recognized* DOCTYPE to ensure non-Quirks mode**

The HTML4 transitional DOCTYPE [listed in the W3C informational reference](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) *includes* the DTD URI:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Per the mode-matrix listing in the [Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) wikipedia article `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">` (without the system identifier) *will* put IE8+ into Quirks mode. Oops.

(Note that even with the transitional system identifier, it is still in the *Almost-standards* mode! Best it to use a Strict DTD and/or the HTML5 DOCTYPE so that recent browsers will run in Standards mode.)

See Quentin's comment for some solutions - *after* fixing the DOCTYPE to ensure Almost-standards/Standards mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can force MSIE to the latest version available using this meta tag inside your head>:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```